# Array of coordinates to SVG Polygon shape

Tags: python, algorithm, svg, polygon

I'm making a random map generator in Python. I am generating random political territories. I have an algorithm that generates a list of X,Y coordinates for a list of territories. These territories do not need to be contiguous, so the list of points can produce multiple polygonal shapes.

Currently, I'm converting the list of points into a Path string, essentially a very long line that wraps around to form a shape. Not exactly what Path was intended for. It's also very inefficient; if you have an especially long territory it can get to be several thousand character long. Also, using this method makes the stroke property essentially act like the fill property, meaning I can't draw a border line between territories.

[Here's an example of what I'm doing now](http://jsfiddle.net/S5PSk/):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="512" height="512">
    <path d="M 332 263 H 346 M 331 264 H 347 M 330 265 H 348 M 329 266 H 349 M 328 267 H 350 M 327 268 H 351 M 326 269 H 352 M 325 270 H 364 M 324 271 H 365 M 323 272 H 366 M 322 273 H 367 M 321 274 H 368 M 320 275 H 369 M 319 276 H 370 M 318 277 H 371 M 317 278 H 372 M 317 279 L 317 279 M 319 279 M 322 279 H 373 M 318 280 L 318 280 M 323 280 H 374 M 317 281 L 317 281 M 324 281 H 375 M 322 282 L 322 282 M 324 282 H 376 M 320 283 H 376 M 321 284 H 376 M 321 285 H 323 M 325 285 H 330 M 333 285 M 340 285 H 375 M 323 286 H 324 M 326 286 H 328 M 342 286 H 371 M 373 286 H 374 M 325 287 L 325 287 M 327 287 M 345 287 H 373 M 346 288 H 372 M 345 289 H 372 M 346 290 H 369 M 372 290 M 375 290 M 345 291 H 368 M 371 291 M 374 291 H 377 M 345 292 H 368 M 374 292 H 375 M 344 293 H 367 M 344 294 H 363 M 365 294 M 343 295 H 362 M 344 296 H 363 M 343 297 H 363 M 345 298 H 363 M 345 299 H 363 M 345 300 H 363 M 345 301 H 361 M 344 302 H 361 M 345 303 H 361 M 346 304 H 357 M 347 305 H 356 M 350 306 H 351 M 354 306 M 356 306" stroke="rgb(252, 81, 193)">
    </path>
</svg>
```

**The actual question:**
How can I convert a list of points to one or more polygons? More specifically, I need a polygon "lines" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your territory generating algorithm is based on a bitmap.  What you need is to trace the outline of the shape rather than making the SVG by "run-length encoding" the shape as you are doing now.

Describing how to do that is a bit beyond a S.O. answer.  In the general sense this is called "bitmap tracing". A popular library for this is `potrace`. I think there are python bindings for it.

Otherwise, it may be you can do a better job (than potrace) by taking advantage of the internal data structures that your territory algorithm builds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your SVG shape currently looks like:

[image]

Rather than an exact outline solution, I would suggest you could generate your map at a lower resolution and then use a [marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) algorithm to convert to a high-res vector format.